# How to convert .py script and .ui file with images to .exe

Tags: python

I wrote a program in Python that includes external files, including images and a GUI .ui file.

I want to convert the Python script to a single executable (.exe) file using PyInstaller. When I try to open the .exe file, the program does not open.

Answer (score 0):

You will need more information on why the application is closing immediately in order to solve your problem. To view the error messages associated with running your executable, run the .exe file from the command prompt: `/path/to/app/dist/MyApp.exe`. This will allow you to observe any errors that may exist after the app was bundled. If the program fails during an import statement, you may need to add a package to the hiddenimports list in the .spec file. Check the [PyInstaller documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/spec-files.html) for instructions on modifying the .spec file.